# Doing linear regression in Torch gives NaN as error

Tags: lua, neural-network, linear-regression, torch, mean-square-error

I am new for torch. Recently, I am trying to use torch to do multi-linear regression. But the error is always being infinity and nan.

For the first two error, it is obviously increasing.
Here is my code.

```
dataset= 
124.0000   81.6900   64.5000  118.0000
 150.0000  103.8400   73.3000  143.0000
   ...
 137.0000   94.9600   67.0000  191.0000
 110.0000   99.7900   75.5000  192.0000
   ...
  94.0000   89.4000   64.5000  139.0000
  74.0000   93.0000   74.0000  148.0000
  89.0000   93.5900   75.5000  179.0000
linLayer = nn.Linear(3,1)
model = nn.Sequential()  
model:add(linLayer)
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()

feval = function(x_new)
    if x ~= x_new then
      x:copy(x_new)
   end
   _nidx_ = (_nidx_ or 0) + 1
   if _nidx_ > (#dataset_inputs)[1] then _nidx_ = 1 end

   local sample = dataset[_nidx_]
   local inputs = sample[{ {2,4} }]
   local target = sample[{ {1} }] 

   dl_dx:zero()

   local loss_x = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs),target)
   model:backward(inputs, criterion:backward(model.output,target))

   -- return loss(x) and dloss/dx
   return loss_x, dl_dx
end


sgd_params = {
   learningRate = 1e-3,
   learningRateDecay = 1e-4,
   weightDecay = 0,
   momentum = 0
}
epochs = 100


  for i = 1,epochs do
        current_loss = 0
        for i = 1,(#dataset_inputs)[1] do

            _,fs = optim.sgd(feval,x,sgd_params)

            current_loss = current_loss + fs[1]
        end
        current_loss = current_loss / (#dataset_inputs)[1]
        print('epoch = ' .. i .. 
         ' of ' .. epochs .. 
         ' current loss = ' .. current_loss)
    end

And the result:
epoch = 1 of 100 current loss = 8.1958765768632e+138    
epoch = 2 of 100 current loss = 5.0759297005752e+278    
epoch = 3 of 100 current loss = inf 
epoch = 4 of 100 current loss = inf 
epoch = 5 of 100 current loss = nan 
... ...
epoch = 97 of 100 current loss = nan    
epoch = 98 of 100 current loss = nan    
epoch = 99 of 100 current loss = nan    
epoch = 100 of 100 current loss = nan
```

What should I do for this problem? And I use the same way for train logistic regression. The result seems better than this. But still not good enough. 
Is there something wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. I suppose you're following Nando de Freitas course? Did you solve it?

Comment: Oh I actually solved, it just by tweaking the learningRate, and learningRateDecay. The convergence is very sensitive on those..

Comment: Thank you so much, guillefix. It helps me a lot.